# How paste command into WinSCP terminal window?

Tags: windows, shell, winscp

I need to enter code into WinSCP terminal.

How can I do that besides typing each symbol?

How can I simply copy and paste the command lines?

I tried "Ctrl+V" -  doesnt work.

[image]

Does it required some different keyboard combination in order to paste test?

Comment: Do you get a context menu if you right click on the window?

Comment: I do not. I opening terminal by double clicking on WinSCP.com file.

Comment: Oh, If I right click on a blue edge - it gives me that option. Thanks for the idea. Please post an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Oleg Please check my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Righ-click on the Window header → Edit → Paste:
[image]

**UPD:** By the way, if you want to paste it without doing this every time, right-click on the Window header, choose "Properties", enable "QuickEdit Mode", and click "OK". Now you can paste strings with a single "right-click".

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to the answer by @Victor, since Windows 10, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> (and its companions) can be enabled using the console option *Enable Ctrl key shortcuts* (I actually believe that the option is enabled by default).